# Def. of total probability on wiki

Tags: probability, measure-theory

As following:

[image]

I am confused about "**Bn is measurable**". Bn is measurable means Bn is a sigmal-algebra. 
According to the definition of sigma-algebra:

Bn must contain whole sample space, empty space; however, I think it is not because 
Bn is included in the sample space.

What happen here?

Thanks!

Comment: $B_n$ being measurable means $B_n$ is **in** a certain sigma-algebra.

Comment: Thanks..I know where I miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure $\rm{Pr}$ is defined on a certain $\sigma$-algebra, say $\mathcal{M}$. The assumption that each $B_n$ is measurable simply means $B_n \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $n$.